# Python script slowing down over time

Tags: python, performance

I have a python 3 script, that is basically data scraper from an API.

The code itself is working fine and the speed is spectacular, but it gets slower over time.

I have no idea on how to go about finding why it get's slower.

A simple outline of how it works is this:

1. Script calls for an API dataset that is returned as JSON and converted to a list full with dictionaries.
2. The dictionary list is looped trough and checked against multiple criteria.
3. If match is found, a CSV file is opened and the result is written in there.
4. After all the data have been tested against certainc riteria (with simple If statements) then all the data is recorded in a CSV file.
5. After CSV file contains more than 100 data points every time a new one comes in the last one is popped out.
6. Repeat.

Now all is fine, until the script has ran for about 24 hours. Then the loop speed will be around 32seconds per loop, and slowly it will keep increasing over time.

My question is - what could cause this? and where do I look what could cause this.

Please do let me know what additional info I need to provide if I've left out some paramount peace of info.

Comment: You should provide a [minimal, complete and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) for us to be able to identify the problem. You're just giving us a description of your algorithm, but the performance issues will surely fall in the implementation (probably memory leaks). Without code it's hard to tell if your implementation has any performance issues at all.

Answer (score 0):

Typically if something is slowing down overtime, then I test for at least two items by default.

1. Check to see if garbage collection will help. If objects are constantly being saved over, ie `same_name = new_object`, then the memory of the original `same_name` is not being released. This could cause performance to degrade in addition to reducing available memory. A simple `import gc` and then `gc.collect()` being ran occasionally could help.
2. An object continues to grow in size. If this is the case, and I don't know if it is because I haven't seen your code, then it could help to store chunks of the object using pickle. After a specified size is met, then store the object and start over.

To continue to narrow it down, perhaps you could add timers throughout your code (especially in places that you least expect to be an issue), and either print or write the timing data to a log file. I just use `from time import time`, and then `start_time = time()` followed by `end_time = time()` to get the total seconds an operation took through `end_time - start_time`. This information can help you to see where the code is starting to take longer. Storing this data in a table would help make it easier to consume and analyze and label the time data by some name that helps you know exactly where the information was collected in your code.

If you happen to take that step, add the new information to your question to help us better assist you.